# complex line integral of a real-valued function (with domain in $\mathbb C$)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\colon\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$, and let $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ be a smooth parametrization. Then we define the complex line integral of $f$ as
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=\int f(z(t))z'(t)\,dt.
$$
I'm confused about one thing. What if we have a real $f$, that is to say $f(z)\in\mathbb R$ for each $z\in\mathbb C$. Then if we look at $\int f(z(t))z'(t)dt$, we see that it is complex, because $z'(t)$ is complex. But one would expect that our integral is still real, no? It seems like I'm making an error, but I don't see where.

Comment: Why *would* you expect it to be real? $dz$ is a complex quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason that $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$ should be real.  Let's take $f(z) = 1$, and $\gamma$ the line from $0$ to $i$.  Then the integral is just $z|^i_0 = i$.